# UCC SSL with Cpanel/WHM

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, web-server

Is it possible to setup Cpanel/WHM with a [UCC certificate](http://help.godaddy.com/article/3908)?  If so, how do I go about doing that?

Comment: I don't know Cpanel/WHM what about it makes it matter how SSL is implemented? I'm using a UCC SSL on IIS and it satisfies my needs.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to add the extra SAN names in the CSR with cPanel but most SSL providers allow you to add those in the order process. So, yes, you can use a UC Certificate with cPanel. Just specify the SANs when ordering.

Comment: It looks like you have to manually add the extra VirtualHosts to the httpd.conf file, but otherwise it works